# How to connect dockerized spring boot app to dockerized postgres

Tags: spring, postgresql, maven, docker, microservices

I have to write 3 simple microservices, using spring boot, and dockerize them. Since I have just started reading about dockers I have encountered several issues.

To build docker images I am using this maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <imageName>example</imageName>
        <baseImage>java</baseImage>
        <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <imageTags>
            <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
        </imageTags>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

**Requirements**

- Docker containers have to run without ROOT user privilages.
- Building maven script should build docker containers.
- Database also needs to be dockerized (all microservices use one database)

**My issues**

I have test service .jar and everything works just fine (it connects to dockerized postgres) but when I run docker image (built with sudo mvn docker:build) of test service .jar I can't connect to postgres.

I have found that localhost in data source might be the issue:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dockertest
```

But I don't know what should I put in place of localhost.

---

I would appreciate any tips on how to easily create and run those docker images (meeting above requirements)

Answer (score 1):

Docker wont see your localhost.
You have to create a network, and join with all the services (see `docker network` cli command)
Then use the app's docker name to refere it in the network (if name is abc-service then use `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://abc-service/dockertest`).

Or you can use **docker compose**, which will auto create the network for your services.

example docker-compose.yml:

`version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  eureka-server:
    build: ./eureka-server
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"
  book-service:
    build: ./book-service
    build: ./writer-service`

then connect like this in proper services' application.yml:

`redis:
  host: redis-server
  port: 6379`